# TCP/IP Server Using sockets Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ip

I am trying to make a server in Java to interact with browser using TCP/IP sockets. When the IP address is entered (localhost:8080), it should serve an HTML page with a button that sends a POST request to server which should just print "Hello from browser" + clientId (A client is given a random int ID when connecting to a server) in terminal. I am running into an issue where when entering the IP address it connects the user twice to the socket (maybe sending multiple resources) and when pressing the button to send the POST request it also acts as if a new user is connecting to the socket. [Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqINb.png)

Below is my code for Server and the ClientHandler classes:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server {
    private static final int PORT = 8080;
    private static final String HTML_FILE_PATH = "src/main/java/org/example/index.html"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); // For handling client threads

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            System.out.println("Server started on port " + PORT);

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(clientSocket);
                    executor.submit(clientHandler); // Handle the client connection in a new thread
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Error accepting client connection: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            executor.shutdown(); // Properly shut down the executor service when the server is stopping
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    private static final AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger(0); // For generating unique IDs
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private int clientId;
    private static final String HTML_FILE_PATH = "src/main/java/org/example/index.html"; 

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.clientId = nextId.incrementAndGet(); // Assign a unique ID to this client
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
             BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()))) {

            System.out.println("Client " + clientId + " connected: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());

            // Handle the incoming HTTP request here
            String line;
            StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (!(line = reader.readLine()).isBlank()) {
                requestBuilder.append(line).append("\r\n");
            }
            String request = requestBuilder.toString();

            // Parse the request line
            String[] requestLines = request.split("\r\n");
            String[] requestLine = requestLines[0].split(" ");
            String method = requestLine[0];
            String path = requestLine[1];

            if (method.equals("GET")) {
                if (path.equals("/")) {
                    serveFile(HTML_FILE_PATH, writer);
                } else {
                    // Respond with a 404 (Not Found) for other GET requests
                    writeResponse(writer, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found", "text/plain", "Not Found".getBytes(), false);
                }
            } else if (method.equals("POST")) {
                // Read and print the data from the POST request
                int contentLength = getContentLength(requestLines);
                char[] body = new char[contentLength];
                reader.read(body, 0, contentLength);
                String postData = new String(body);
                String decodedData = URLDecoder.decode(postData, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("POST data from Client " + clientId + ": " + decodedData);

                
                writeResponse(writer, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "text/plain", "Data received".getBytes(), false);
            }
            else {
                // Method not supported
                writeResponse(writer, "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed", "text/plain", "Unsupported method".getBytes(), false);
            }

            writer.flush();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error handling client " + clientId + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void serveFile(String filePath, BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            writeResponse(writer, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "text/html", fileContent, false);
        } else {
            writeResponse(writer, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found", "text/plain", "File not found".getBytes(), false);
        }
    }

    private void writeResponse(BufferedWriter writer, String statusLine, String contentType, byte[] content, boolean keepAlive) throws IOException {
        writer.write(statusLine + "\r\n");
        writer.write("Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n");
        writer.write("Content-Length: " + content.length + "\r\n");
        if (keepAlive) {
            writer.write("Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
            writer.write("Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100\r\n"); 
        } else {
            writer.write("Connection: close\r\n");
        }
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.write(new String(content));
    }
    private int getContentLength(String[] requestHeaders) {
        for (String header : requestHeaders) {
            if (header.startsWith("Content-Length:")) {
                return Integer.parseInt(header.split(":")[1].trim());
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I am trying to make sure that once the IP address is entered by a user they stay in the server as one connection and not keep connecting again (Like a session) because I am planning on making a 2 player game based off of this simple implementation first.

I have tried using keep-alive header but that was not successful. Either wrong implementation or did not solve the problem

[Assignment_Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwEvI.png)

Comment: You have correctly described the permissible behaviour of the browser. What is your question?

Comment: @user207421 I want it so that once they connect it registers them in the server and not keep connecting again after sending POST requests or have double multiple connection when entering the IP address. This is for my 2 player game I am working on.

Comment: You can’t completelycontrol the behaviour of the browser, but you could start by not closing the client socket after processing one request. Use a loop, and a read timeout control how long you keep receiving in each connection.

Comment: @Teahana: I recommend that you make yourself familiar with the HTTP standard and don't make assumptions on how the browser works. HTTP is a standard, read it. What you see is perfectly normal behavior. You have to work with what HTTP gives you, not try to change how the browser behaves.  Please note also that fields (like content-length) are case insensitive.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich oh okay, will read on that. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should think about implementing dedicated clients for your 2-player-game instead of abusing a browser. Alternatively, you should consider to use a web container like Tomcat or Jetty (or even a full-fledged application server) as the base for you server. At least, your server should not be built on bare TCP sockets … You may want to have a look what's in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.httpserver/module-summary.html for your project …

Comment: @tquadrat It is for my assignment, I don't think I am allowed to use web containers such as those. Or maybe I am mis-understanding the assignment. Is it okay if I send you the specification of the assignment and you tell me if I am mis-understanding it? It is not long

Comment: Perhaps you can add the assignment specification to the question?

Comment: @Teahana If you really 'see' why did you repost your question with what appears to be exactly the same code and no sign of the two features I mentioned?